# Specify database path for QMYSQL

Tags: qt, mariadb, qt6, qsqldatabase

Qt 6.2.0, Ubuntu 21.10.
Usually `MariaDb` stores database under `/var/lib/mysql/` directory.

I can connect to my own database using this working code:

```
_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "machines");
_db.setHostName("localhost");
_db.setDatabaseName("mydb");
_db.setUserName("user");
_db.setPassword("password");
```

qDebug() << _db.open();  // true

I copied the database to another location:

```
$ sudo cp -r /var/lib/mysql/mydb /home/mark/mydir/
```

Changing the database name to:

```
_db.setDatabaseName("/home/mark/mydir/mydb");
```

leads to fail when `open()` is called.
The error is:

> QMYSQL: Unable to connect", "Unknown database 'home/mark/mydir/mydb'

What is the correct syntax do specify a different path?

Comment: there is no path to be entered the databse name is mydb

Comment: @nbk only if you want to use the default location

Comment: @Mark: No - If you want the database files lying on another directory then you have to specify it in the mysql config, not when you're doing a connection to a db (not matter if it is Qt or anything other)

Comment: in the database name is not possible to9 define the location, yyou can only change the my.cnf to redirect the location. try it pleas

Answer (score 1):

mysql does not locate database using path, you have to specify the database name instead